# Java EE 6 on Glassfish v4

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6

Is it possible to use the new **Glassfish 4** application server to run existing **Java EE 6** applications, or it's only for Java EE 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Java EE 7 in general is downwards compatible with Java EE 6 but there may be some updates in the API implementations, e.g. class/interface/method names may have been changed.